#  NSMutableArray insertion in objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

I am using the following code to add NSNumber to a NSMutableArray

in header file:

```
NSNumber *timeInSeconds;
NSMutableArray *time;
```

in code:

```
int total=6;
timeInSeconds=[NSNumber numberWithInt:total];
[time addObject:timeInSeconds];
```

However, while debugging, I noticed that if I do

```
print (int) [time count]
```

I get an output of 0 ... Not sure why this is happening...can anyone kindly help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see where you allocated `time`. At some point you need to call

```
time = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

or some other allocation and initialization method.

Comment: `> po time` will likely tell you that time == nil - - - `[nil anyMessage] == nil` - - - - `(int)nil == 0`